# How to set slider revolution full width

Tags: jquery, html, revolution-slider

I'm new with slider revolution. How can I make it full width screen? I tried following:

```
                <!-- START REVOLUTION SLIDER 5.0 -->
                <div class="rev_slider_wrapper">
                    <div id="slider1" class="rev_slider"  data-version="5.0">
                        <ul>
                            <li data-transition="fade">
                                <!-- MAIN IMAGE -->
                                <img src="../img/iphone.jpg"  alt=""  width="1920" height="1280">
                            </li>

                            <li data-transition="fade">
                                <!-- MAIN IMAGE -->
                                <img src="../img/htc.png"  alt=""  width="1920" height="1280">
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div><!-- END REVOLUTION SLIDER -->
                </div><!-- END OF SLIDER WRAPPER -->

                <script>
                    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                        jQuery("#slider1").revolution({
                            sliderType:"standard",
                            sliderLayout:"fullwidth",
                            delay:9000,
                            navigation: {
                                arrows:{enable:true}
                            }
                        });
                    });
                </script>
```

But it is still half width. I included everything in the header.

Comment: can you provide a codepen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you could attach a screen shot it maybe easier to answer but you could try something like

---

```
<div class="rev_slider_wrapper" style="width:100%">
```